# How do I use Google Script If Statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am familiar with Excel VBA but am new to Google Script Editing

I am trying to use a simple IF statement to insert a new line above line 2 if cells A2 & B2 are NOT Blank.

```
  function AddaLine() {
if (B1 == false)
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
};
```

where cell B1 contains

```
=isblank(A2:B2)
```

or

```
function AddaLine() {
  if (A2, B2 != null)
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
};
```

Every combination I can think of returns errors.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `I am trying to use a simple IF statement to insert a new line above line 2 if cells A2 & B2 are NOT Blank.`, you want to insert a new row to the row 2 when the cells "A2" and "B2" are not empty.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function AddaLine() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var [a2, b2] = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:B2").getDisplayValues()[0];
  if (a2 != "" && b2 != "") {
    spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
    spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  }
}
```

Or, for example, as a simple script, how about the following modification?

```js
function AddaLine() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var [a2, b2] = sheet.getRange("A2:B2").getDisplayValues()[0];
  if (a2 != "" && b2 != "") {
    sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
  }
}
```

- In order to check whether the cells "A2" and "B2" are not empty, I compared the values retrieved from the cells.

#### Note:

- As the additional information by advising from [Rubén's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69784191/how-do-i-use-google-script-if-statements/69784396?noredirect=1#comment123359638_69784396), in your script, you use the following script.

  ```
    if (A2, B2 != null)
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    spreadsheet.getRange('2:2').activate();
  ```

  In this case, when the the condition is `true`, only the line of `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` is run. When you want to use the script below `if (A2, B2 != null)`, please enclose them by `{}`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: As the OP isn't familiar with Google Apps Script / JavaScript, it might be important to highlight the use of `{}` on if-statements and the problems related to automatic line termination.

Answer (score 0):

Rather for educational purpose. If you want to check all elements of an array you can use `every()` method:

```
function AddaLine() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:B2").getDisplayValues().flat(); 
  if (data.every(x => x != '')) sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
}
```

- [JavaScript Array every()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_every.asp)

Alternatively, in your case, you can use `some()` to check if some of the elements is empty:

```
function AddaLine() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("A2:B2").getDisplayValues().flat();
  if (data.some(x => x == '')) return; // do nothing if there is an empty cell
  sheet.insertRowBefore(2);
}
```

- [JavaScript Array some()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp)

Probably `somme()` will be a little bit more efficient since it doesn't need to check all elements of the array.